# Different names for Fidaxomicin (OPT-80)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, medicinal-chemistry

Is OPT in OPT-80 an abbreviation? If so, what is the full name?

Answer (score 2):

Fidaxomicin is the [International nonproprietary name (INN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_nonproprietary_name) of a pharmaceutical, which was/is distributed by different companies under different trade names.

To my knowledge, **OPT**-80 was a provisional name/signature used by ***Opt***imer Pharmaceuticals Inc.. The drug was later sold as *Dificid*.